# Cannot initiate GeoFirestore instance in node.js application

Tags: node.js, geofirestore

I use GeoFirestore in my node.js application. In the first lines of the document i have:

```
var GeoFirestore = require("geofirestore");
```

And then i use the code

```
const geoFirestore = new GeoFirestore(collectionRef);
```

With the collectionRef being a valid ref to the my firestore collection.

The issue is that i get the error

> "TypeError: GeoFirestore is not a constructor"

What is the problem here? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `index.js` of geofirestore exports a few different files, so I can say your import wouldn't work. I believe you would want to do this (if you're not using Typescript or an ES6+):

```
var GeoFirestore = require("geofirestore").GeoFirestore;
```

Let me know if that works for you.